# ifstream is.open() acting like it's not reading the file

Tags: c++, fstream

```
//Prompts user for a file name and stores it
string fileName;

cout << "Enter the file name: ";
cin >> fileName;

ifstream inFile (fileName);
inFile.open(fileName);

//Prompt the user until they give the name of a file that can be opened
bool validFileName = false;
while(validFileName == false)
{
    if(inFile.is_open())
    {
        validFileName = true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid file name: ";
        cin >> fileName;

        ifstream inFile;
        inFile.open(fileName);
    }
 }
//this block prints to the terminal, so it's opening
 if(inFile.is_open())
 { cout << "It works! \n"; }
```

I am trying to create a program that will work with a file, but there needs to be a section that checks to see if the file that the user types in is an actual file that the program can open. I've tried a few different ways to write the while loop, because it needs to keep asking until it receives a valid file. I have the valid file name "input.txt", but even when I type that into the terminal it continues to print the error message. I have tried to type the file name with and without quotes, so I'm not sure what it is caught up on. I know it is opening the file, because I added a second check afterward and it appears that it's opening, so I think it's an issue with how I have the error check statement written?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(fileName);
```

in the loop. The variable in the loop hides the variable of the same name outside the loop. Remove the first of those lines.

---

FWIW, you can simplify your code to:

```
ifstream inFile (fileName);

while(!inFile)
{
   // Prompt the user until they give the name of a file that can be opened
   cout << "Please enter a valid file name: ";
   cin >> fileName;

   inFile.open(fileName);
}

if(inFile)
{
   cout << "It works! \n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
ifstream inFile (fileName);
inFile.open(fileName);
```

The file is opened on the first line.
Reopening it is redundant.

Also in the loop you declare a temporary variable inFile which goes out of stop at the end of the else statement. Make sure to declare it only once at the outmost scope you would like to use it.

Comment: While that is redundant, that is not really the cause of the problem.